# Correcting Maximum and minimum Y axis

Tags: r, plot

I would like to display a plot in which plankton tow data is displayed in the range of 0-40 m BSL (below sea level) and core top data in the depth of 50-80 m. Of course, 0 m BSL should be at the top of the Y axis, but the code:

```
plankton_tow <- data.frame(DO <- c(-1.2, -0.8, -0.5, -1.5), depth = c(-10, -20, -30, -40))
core_tops <- data.frame(DO <- c(-2.0, -1.6, -1.3, -2.5), depth = c(-50, -60, -70, -80))

plankton_tow$depth <- min(plankton_tow$depth) - plankton_tow$depth
core_tops$depth <- min(core_tops$depth) - core_tops$depth


par(pty = "s")  


plot(plankton_tow$DO, plankton_tow$depth, xlim = range(c(plankton_tow$DO, core_tops$DO)), ylim = c(0, min (core_tops$depth)),
     xlab = expression(delta^18*O ~ "[‰] vs. PDB"), ylab = "Depth [m BSL]", 
     pch = 16, col = "black", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
points(core_tops$DO, core_tops$depth, pch = 21, col = "black")



axis(side = 1, at = seq(min(plankton_tow$DO, core_tops$DO), max(plankton_tow$DO, core_tops$DO), by = 0.5))
axis(side = 2, at = seq(0, max(plankton_tow$depth, core_tops$depth), by = 10), labels = rev(seq(0, max(plankton_tow$depth, core_tops$depth), by = 10)))
```

[image]

As you can see, the data for the core top, for example, is at 0 m BSL and not at 50 m bsl <... I don't know why the depth resolution does not exist in this plot. I must have made some mistake that I don't see and unfortunately R doesn't show me an error message.

If I use: ylim = c( min(core_tops$depth),0. I get this: however the samples arent in the same depth. So what Im doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I do not quite understand your issue. Please elaborate on the expected output.

Comment: Hi @Friede sorry :e I fixed it I hope it is now more clear :)

Comment: Looking at your data, I see a max depth of -30.  There is no way to display something at -50 or |-50| based on the data.

Comment: But the core tops are -80 m (Im quite new to coding)

Comment: You are using `core_tops$depth` to plot y-vals. Have a look at `core_tops` after you have executing the first four lines of the code given above.

Comment: You should have `ylim=c(min(core_tops$depth), 0)`.

Comment: Is this your "real" data? Your use of `data.frame(DO <- c(` means that there is not really a `$DO` column, instead there is now a `DO` object in your global environment. (Almost) "Never" use `<-` inside a function call, that is the one place where `<-` and `=` are _very different_. (To be clear, the first column name is not `"DO"`, it is `"DO....c..1.2...0.8...0.5...1.5."`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is that the y-axis is not showing what you need. There are a few places where you work with `seq` and `range` and `min`/`max`, and I suspect you updated all but one or so.

I suggest to prevent accidentally missing one (or more) of these limits/ranges, you precalculate them into variables.

(Fixed) Sample data:

```r
plankton_tow <- data.frame(DO = c(-1.2, -0.8, -0.5, -1.5), depth = c(-10, -20, -30, -40))
core_tops <- data.frame(DO = c(-2.0, -1.6, -1.3, -2.5), depth = c(-50, -60, -70, -80))
plankton_tow$depth <- min(plankton_tow$depth) - plankton_tow$depth
core_tops$depth <- min(core_tops$depth) - core_tops$depth
```

Plot code. I am inferring that you want the y-axis numbers to be positive-numbers indicating negative-elevation (positive depth). If you want `-30` instead of the `30` shown here, just remove the `labels=` part of `axis(2, ..)`.

```r
xlims <- range(c(plankton_tow$DO, core_tops$DO))
ylims <- c(min(core_tops$depth), 0)
par(pty = "s")  
plot(plankton_tow$DO, plankton_tow$depth,
     xlim = xlims, ylim = ylims,
     xlab = expression(delta^18*O ~ "[‰] vs. PDB"), ylab = "Depth [m BSL]", 
     pch = 16, col = "black", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
points(core_tops$DO, core_tops$depth, pch = 21, col = "black")
axis(side = 1, at = seq(xlims[1], xlims[2], by = 0.5))
axis(side = 2, at = seq(ylims[1], ylims[2], by = 10),
     labels = abs(seq(ylims[1], ylims[2], by = 10)))
```

[image: base graphics]

As a suggestion, you might find `ggplot2` to be a worthy plot as well. To use it, it would help to have the data combined into one frame (with an added "source" variable).

I'm using `dplyr` (and `tibble`) with this since they are often installed as well, but if you don't want to (or cannot) use them this can be altered to be `ggplot2` only (with base R functions).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
xlims <- range(c(plankton_tow$DO, core_tops$DO))
ylims <- c(min(core_tops$depth), 0)
bind_rows(tibble::lst(plankton_tow, core_tops), .id="source") |>
  ggplot(aes(DO, depth, shape = source)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(
    name = NULL,
    values = c(plankton_tow = 16, core_tops = 21)) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    name = expression(delta^18*O ~ "[‰] vs. PDB"),
    limits = xlims, breaks = seq(xlims[1], xlims[2], by = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Depth [m BSL]",
    limits = ylims, breaks = seq(ylims[1], ylims[2], by = 10),
    labels = ~ abs(.)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image: ggplot of the same data]

Notes:

- `lst` automatically names the objects as their object names, otherwise it is just `list`, so if you want to control the legend names instead of `"plankton_tow"`, just set the names with (e.g.) `bind_rows(Plankton = plankton_tow, ..., .id="source")`
- I used `shape=source`, you could just as easily uses `color=source` to different colors instead (then replacing `scale_shape_manual` with `scale_color_manual`) ... or you can use both if you really want to break them apart
- I used `theme_minimal()` to better approximate the black/white austerity of base graphics; feel free to explore *without* this line to see what `ggplot2` defaults to doing.
- Similar to the base-graphics plot, I show positive depths; if you want `-30` instead, remove the `labels=~abs(.)`.