# 3 plots (grid) from 2 different databases

Tags: r, plot

I have the following databases. Database 1 serves as the basis for the Core Tops depicted in the code.

```
structure(list(Nr = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Name = c("Name1", 
"Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", "Name6", "Name7", "Name8", 
"Name9"), Side_Id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Lat = c(63.867467, 
63.867467, 63.867467, 63.867467, 63.867467, 63.867467, 63.867467, 
63.867467, 63.867467), Long = c(-28.946983, -28.946983, -28.946983, 
-28.946983, -28.946983, -28.946983, -28.946983, -28.946983, -28.946983
), `MBSL [m]` = c(300, 490, 560, 729, 424, 535, 232, 243, 644
), `18O` = c(-3, -1.5, -1.62, -1.83, -1.92, -3, -4.2, -2.312, 
-1.12), Age_Top = c("holocene", "holocene", "holocene", "holocene", 
"holocene", "holocene", "holocene", "holocene", "holocene"), 
    Info = c("MUC", "MUC", "MUC", "MUC", "MUC", "MUC", "MUC", 
    "MUC", "MUC"), Region = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), Source = c("Source 1", 
    "Source 2", "Source 3", "Source 4", "Source 5", "Source 6", 
    "Source 7", "Source 8", "Source 9")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Database 2 serves as the basis for the Plankton Tows depicted in the code.

```
structure(list(Nr = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Name = c("NameTow1", 
"NameTow2", "NameTow3", "NameTow4", "NameTow5", "NameTow6", "NameTow7", 
"NameTow8", "NameTow9"), Side_Id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9), Lat = c(63.867467, 63.867467, 63.867467, 63.867467, 63.867467, 
63.867467, 63.867467, 63.867467, 63.867467), Long = c(-28.946983, 
-28.946983, -28.946983, -28.946983, -28.946983, -28.946983, -28.946983, 
-28.946983, -28.946983), `MBSL [m]` = c(0, 2, 5, 2, 10, 2, 5, 
20, 30), `18O` = c(-1.2, -0.9, -1.2, -0.83, -6.32, -0.02, -0.8, 
-1.1, -1.12), Age_Top = c("holocene", "holocene", "holocene", 
"holocene", "holocene", "holocene", "holocene", "holocene", "holocene"
), Info = c("MUC", "MUC", "MUC", "MUC", "MUC", "MUC", "MUC", 
"MUC", "MUC"), Region = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), Source = c("Source 9", 
"Source 10", "Source 11", "Source 12", "Source 13", "Source 14", 
"Source 15", "Source 16", "Source 17")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Two row informations are important. 1. The row Region. I have divided the example data into 3 regions: 1. Labrador 2. Greenland 3. Iceland. The second important information is MBSL [m], which represents the depth of the data.

Now I want to create 3 plots from these datasets that are displayed side by side and use the following code:

```
plankton_tow <- read_excel(pathdatabase2, Region == 1)
core_tops <- read_excel(pathdatabase1, Region == 1)


#Data Labrador 
xlims_lab <- range(c(plankton_tow$18O, core_tops$18O))
ylims_lab <- c(min(core_tops$depth), 0)
par(pty = "s") 
plot_Lab <- plot(plankton_tow$18O, plankton_tow$depth,
       xlim = xlims_lab, ylim = ylims_lab,
       xlab = expression(delta^18*O ~ "[‰] vs. PDB"), ylab = "Depth [m BSL]", 
       pch = 16, col = "black", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
       points(core_tops$18O, core_tops$depth, pch = 21, col = "black")
       axis(side = 1, at = seq(xlims_lab[1], xlims_lab[2], by = 0.5))
       axis(side = 2, at = seq(ylims_lab[1], ylims_lab[2], by = 10),
       labels = abs(seq(ylims_lab[1], ylims_lab[2], by = 10)))

plankton_tow2 <- read_excel(pathdatabase2, Region == 2)
core_tops2 <- read_excel(pathdatabase1, Region == 2)       

#Data Greenland
xlims_green <- range(c(plankton_tow2$18O, core_tops2$18O))
ylims_green <- c(min(core_tops2$depth), 0)
plot_green <- plot(plankton_tow2$18O, plankton_tow2$depth,
       xlim = xlims_green, ylim = ylims_green,
       xlab = expression(delta^18*O ~ "[‰] vs. PDB"), ylab = "Depth [m BSL]", 
       pch = 16, col = "black", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
       points(core_tops2$18O, core_tops2$depth, pch = 21, col = "black")
       axis(side = 1, at = seq(xlims_green[1], xlims_green[2], by = 0.5))
       axis(side = 2, at = seq(ylims_green[1], ylims_green[2], by = 10),
       labels = abs(seq(ylims_green[1], ylims_green[2], by = 10)))

plankton_tow3 <- read_excel(pathdatabase2, Region == 3)
core_tops3 <- read_excel(pathdatabase1, Region == 3)   
#Data Iceland
xlims_Iceland <- range(c(plankton_tow3$18O, core_tops$18O))
ylims_Iceland <- c(min(core_tops3$depth), 0)      
plot_Iceland <- plot(plankton_tow3$18O, plankton_tow3$depth,
       xlim = xlims_Iceland, ylim = ylims_Iceland,
       xlab = expression(delta^18*O ~ "[‰] vs. PDB"), ylab = "Depth [m BSL]", 
       pch = 16, col = "black", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
       points(core_tops3$18O, core_tops3$depth, pch = 21, col = "black")
       axis(side = 1, at = seq(xlims_Iceland[1], xlims_Iceland[2], by = 0.5))
       axis(side = 2, at = seq(ylims_Iceland[1], ylims_Iceland[2], by = 10),
       labels = abs(seq(ylims_Iceland[1], ylims_Iceland[2], by = 10)))

       
compar<-grid.arrange(plot_Lab, plot_green, plot_Iceland, ncol = 3)    
plot(compar)
```

The problem is that it doesn't throw an error but also doesn't display any plots. What am I doing wrong, or what can I simplify, because my code is very redundant but I can't solve it any better. The endresult should look like this:
[image]

Comment: It's difficult to get that data into something usable. Can you please [edit] your question and add the results from `dput(head(x,12))` where `x` is each of your `plankton_tow` and `core_tops`? ("12" is not a magic number, something between "big enough to demonstrate" and "please not huge".)

Comment: btw, base `plot(1:2, 3:4)` returns `NULL`, do your `plot_Lab` and `plot_green` objects have something saved in them?

Comment: @r2evans hi I updated  my question :D However I do only  have 12 data enterties

Comment: @r2evans to your secound question. I just copied the code from plot_iceland and changed the parameters which I load above :) I know it is not very elegant

Comment: `Unknown or uninitialised column: \`DO\`.`

Comment: @r2evans sorry I mixed some databases up (I cant publish the real data) so i had to write a new dataframe just for demonstration. But now it is fixed

Comment: Yeah, I get it ... frankly I think your question is how to combine base-graphics plots, it isn't critical what data or args you use for it. I hope my answer provides a good start.

Comment: There will be no error because you are effectively calling `grid.arrange(NULL, NULL, NULL, ncol=3)`. I see nothing to suggest that you aren't using the base `plot(..)`, which means that it is returning _nothing_ (`NULL`). You can't just "want" the return value from a plot function to return something. If you want to combine plots, my answer gives you three options. If you want to combine legends and axis labels, then I suggest (as I did in your last question) that switching to `ggplot2` is likely a better option (using `+ facet_wrap(~source)` or such).

Comment: To be clear, is `is.null(plot_Lab)` true? If not, what does `class(plot_Lab)` return?

Comment: Note that from `?grid.arrange`, it takes *"grobs, gtables, ggplot or trellis objects"*, which `base::plot` is not giving you. Perhaps try https://stackoverflow.com/a/25194694/3358272 for combining base graphics, I haven't tested that answer.

Comment: @r2evans yeah it is null#

Answer (score 1):

`base::plot` returns `NULL`, so you cannot capture its return value and expect to be able to reuse that plot *in that way*.

The simplest way to get multiple base-graphics plots side-by-side is to use [`par(mfrow=)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html) (all same-sized) or `layout(.)` (a lot more control) or `par(fig=)` (fine-tuned, ability to overlay plots).

## par(mfrow=)

```r
par(mfrow = c(1, 2)) # you would use 3 here?
plot(`MBSL [m]` ~ `18O`, data = plankton_tow, main = "Plankton Tow")
plot(`MBSL [m]` ~ `18O`, data = core_tops, main = "Core Tops")
```

The only difference between `par(mfrow=)` and `par(mfcol=)` is that the first plots them by-row first.

[image: base graphics, mfrow]

## layout

With `par(mfrow=)` you control layout with just the number of rows and columns, whereas [`layout`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/layout.html) allows one to control where within a arbitrary grid each plot is based.

The numbers in the matrix are the plot-order, so cells with `1` will be filled with the first call to `plot(.)`. The `0` spaces are null-space, no plots placed there. All number regions must be rectangular.

```r
lay <- matrix(
  c(1, 1, 1, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 2,
    1, 1, 1, 2), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 3)
layout(lay, widths = c(rep(1, 3), 2), heights = c(1, rep(2, 2)))
plot(`MBSL [m]` ~ `18O`, data = plankton_tow, main = "Plankton Tow")
plot(`MBSL [m]` ~ `18O`, data = core_tops, main = "Core Tops")
```

[image: combined plots using layout]

The use of `widths=` and `heights=` is completely optional, but I think you see the power and control of this method.

## par(fig=)

This method allows one to place any plot in any region of the "canvas", allowing similar setups as above but adding the ability to overlay. We always pair it with `par(fig=)`. The default of for fig is `par(fig=c(0,1,0,1))`, meaning to take up the entire canvas, so we'll play with sub-plots. For each one, I'll include a `box(.)` to identify the area of the canvas being used.

```r
par(fig = c(0, 0.7, 0, 0.7))
plot(`MBSL [m]` ~ `18O`, data = plankton_tow, main = "Plankton Tow")
box(which = "figure", col = "red")
par(fig = c(0.3, 1, 0.3, 1), new = TRUE)
plot(`MBSL [m]` ~ `18O`, data = core_tops, main = "Core Tops")
box(which = "figure", col = "green")
```

[image: par(fig)]

Note that the second and subsequent calls to add something to this canvas requires `par(new=TRUE)`.

This method is nuanced with `par(mar=)` effects.

(The use of `ggplot2` as I [previously suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78008122/3358272) would make much of this transparently easy, but I won't be pushy :-)

## cowplot::ggdraw

Another option using `cowplot`, though I find it a little cumbersome because it requires fully plotting each one individually first.

```r
plot(`MBSL [m]` ~ `18O`, data = plankton_tow, main = "Plankton Tow")
p1 <- recordPlot()
plot(`MBSL [m]` ~ `18O`, data = core_tops, main = "Core Tops")
p2 <- recordPlot()
cowplot::plot_grid(cowplot::ggdraw(p1), cowplot::ggdraw(p2))
```

[image: cowplot]

Comment: Hi Thank you! However I think I comunicate wrong! See my uptaded question hoever thank you so much for your time

Comment: See my edit @Weiss. I'm running out of ideas. You cannot fix the fact that `plot(.)` returns `NULL`, so if you don't want to plot it _once_ in a grid using `par(mfrow=)`, `layout`, or `par(fig=)`, then you'll have to plot multiple times, record them, and plot them again. Base graphics is perhaps limited in this sense, but you keep asking for a capability and I feel like these four options are addressing that need.