# Using if_any() and starts_with() in filter(): why does supplying nonsense column names return whole data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been experimenting with the use of `dplyr::if_any()` within a `dplyr::filter()` function in R. I've noticed that if we pass column names that don't exist in the current data frame (as in the last two examples below), the entire data frame is returned. This seems odd; shouldn't it return a data frame with `nrow = 0`?

Examples:

```
library(dplyr)

nrow(iris) # = 150
iris %>% filter(if_any(starts_with("Sepal"), ~ . > 6)) %>% nrow() # = 61
iris %>% filter(if_any(starts_with("nonsense"), ~ . > 5)) %>% nrow() # = 150
iris %>% filter(if_any(starts_with("nonsense"), ~ . == "more_nonsense")) %>% nrow() # = 150
```

I guess there is some underlying reason for this behavior, but even so, I wondered if we can build some extra safety measures in the code, e.g., to tell the user that no columns exist that start with "nonsense" in the current data frame?

**Update - possible solution?**

I'm not experienced at writing my own functions, but I came up with this. I´m not sure if its reasonable?

```
if_any2 <- function(data, string, helper, ...) {
  stopifnot(
    "No columns found in data with the supplied helper function" = 
      select(data, helper(string, ignore.case=FALSE)) %>% ncol() >= 1
  )
  if_any(.cols = helper(string, ignore.case=FALSE), ...)
}

iris %>% filter(if_any2(data = ., string = "Sepal", helper = starts_with, ~ . == 6.3 | . == 2.8)) %>% nrow() # = 22
```

Comment: My guess is the problem is the condition. `if(FALSE, ~ . > 5)` else return the df untouched. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Yes, this is confusing. Related GH issue https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5738

Comment: Perhaps add a stopifnot() before the filter() to ensure there is at least one column that is selected by the starts_with() ?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the issue is that if_any() checks if, for any of the selected columns, the condition is true. In short, you have selected no columns, so no checks are performed.

To check if any columns exist prior to performing the filter, you could do something like this:

```
v <- "nonsense"

iris %>% {if(any(startsWith(v, colnames(.)))) 
          filter(., if_any(starts_with(v), \(x) x > 6)) 
          else warning("No columns found"); .}
```

Output:

```
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
6            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa
7            4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa
8            5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa
9            4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa
10           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1     setosa
11           5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa
12           4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2     setosa
13           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1     setosa
14           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1     setosa
15           5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2     setosa
16           5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4     setosa
17           5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4     setosa
18           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3     setosa
19           5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3     setosa
20           5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3     setosa
21           5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2     setosa
22           5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4     setosa
23           4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2     setosa
24           5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5     setosa
25           4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2     setosa
26           5.0         3.0          1.6         0.2     setosa
27           5.0         3.4          1.6         0.4     setosa
28           5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2     setosa
29           5.2         3.4          1.4         0.2     setosa
30           4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2     setosa
31           4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2     setosa
32           5.4         3.4          1.5         0.4     setosa
33           5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1     setosa
34           5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2     setosa
35           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
36           5.0         3.2          1.2         0.2     setosa
37           5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2     setosa
38           4.9         3.6          1.4         0.1     setosa
39           4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2     setosa
40           5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa
41           5.0         3.5          1.3         0.3     setosa
42           4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3     setosa
43           4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
44           5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6     setosa
45           5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4     setosa
46           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3     setosa
47           5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2     setosa
48           4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2     setosa
49           5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa
50           5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2     setosa
51           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
52           6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
53           6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
54           5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
55           6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
56           5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
57           6.3         3.3          4.7         1.6 versicolor
58           4.9         2.4          3.3         1.0 versicolor
59           6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 versicolor
60           5.2         2.7          3.9         1.4 versicolor
61           5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0 versicolor
62           5.9         3.0          4.2         1.5 versicolor
63           6.0         2.2          4.0         1.0 versicolor
64           6.1         2.9          4.7         1.4 versicolor
65           5.6         2.9          3.6         1.3 versicolor
66           6.7         3.1          4.4         1.4 versicolor
67           5.6         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor
68           5.8         2.7          4.1         1.0 versicolor
69           6.2         2.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
70           5.6         2.5          3.9         1.1 versicolor
71           5.9         3.2          4.8         1.8 versicolor
72           6.1         2.8          4.0         1.3 versicolor
73           6.3         2.5          4.9         1.5 versicolor
74           6.1         2.8          4.7         1.2 versicolor
75           6.4         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor
76           6.6         3.0          4.4         1.4 versicolor
77           6.8         2.8          4.8         1.4 versicolor
78           6.7         3.0          5.0         1.7 versicolor
79           6.0         2.9          4.5         1.5 versicolor
80           5.7         2.6          3.5         1.0 versicolor
81           5.5         2.4          3.8         1.1 versicolor
82           5.5         2.4          3.7         1.0 versicolor
83           5.8         2.7          3.9         1.2 versicolor
84           6.0         2.7          5.1         1.6 versicolor
85           5.4         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor
86           6.0         3.4          4.5         1.6 versicolor
87           6.7         3.1          4.7         1.5 versicolor
88           6.3         2.3          4.4         1.3 versicolor
89           5.6         3.0          4.1         1.3 versicolor
90           5.5         2.5          4.0         1.3 versicolor
91           5.5         2.6          4.4         1.2 versicolor
92           6.1         3.0          4.6         1.4 versicolor
93           5.8         2.6          4.0         1.2 versicolor
94           5.0         2.3          3.3         1.0 versicolor
95           5.6         2.7          4.2         1.3 versicolor
96           5.7         3.0          4.2         1.2 versicolor
97           5.7         2.9          4.2         1.3 versicolor
98           6.2         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor
99           5.1         2.5          3.0         1.1 versicolor
100          5.7         2.8          4.1         1.3 versicolor
101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica
102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica
103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1  virginica
104          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8  virginica
105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2  virginica
106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1  virginica
107          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7  virginica
108          7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8  virginica
109          6.7         2.5          5.8         1.8  virginica
110          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5  virginica
111          6.5         3.2          5.1         2.0  virginica
112          6.4         2.7          5.3         1.9  virginica
113          6.8         3.0          5.5         2.1  virginica
114          5.7         2.5          5.0         2.0  virginica
115          5.8         2.8          5.1         2.4  virginica
116          6.4         3.2          5.3         2.3  virginica
117          6.5         3.0          5.5         1.8  virginica
118          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2  virginica
119          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3  virginica
120          6.0         2.2          5.0         1.5  virginica
121          6.9         3.2          5.7         2.3  virginica
122          5.6         2.8          4.9         2.0  virginica
123          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0  virginica
124          6.3         2.7          4.9         1.8  virginica
125          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.1  virginica
126          7.2         3.2          6.0         1.8  virginica
127          6.2         2.8          4.8         1.8  virginica
128          6.1         3.0          4.9         1.8  virginica
129          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.1  virginica
130          7.2         3.0          5.8         1.6  virginica
131          7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9  virginica
132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0  virginica
133          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.2  virginica
134          6.3         2.8          5.1         1.5  virginica
135          6.1         2.6          5.6         1.4  virginica
136          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3  virginica
137          6.3         3.4          5.6         2.4  virginica
138          6.4         3.1          5.5         1.8  virginica
139          6.0         3.0          4.8         1.8  virginica
140          6.9         3.1          5.4         2.1  virginica
141          6.7         3.1          5.6         2.4  virginica
142          6.9         3.1          5.1         2.3  virginica
143          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica
144          6.8         3.2          5.9         2.3  virginica
145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5  virginica
146          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3  virginica
147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9  virginica
148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0  virginica
149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3  virginica
150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8  virginica
Warning message:
In iris %>% { : No columns found
```

My code could be edited to use `stop()` or `stopifnot()`, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78095668/using-if-any-and-starts-with-in-filter-why-does-supplying-nonsense-column/78098930#comment137679840_78095668) by user167591.

You could also use the function from [Romain François's comment](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5738#issuecomment-777433105) on the Github issue Ronak Shah posted.

Comment: Thanks so much @Mark. Your solution looks great. Just before I saw this I came up with a possible solution of creating a custom function for this problem (please see update on my question) - though I am not certain whether that is wise in this situation?

Comment: you could just replace the `&` in Romain's function to be a `|`

Comment: you example function seems to give me the error "! `contains()` must be used within a *selecting* function."

Comment: Hi @Mark sorry for missusing this commet section against. I have a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78012514/3-plots-grid-from-2-different-databases there is an answer however it doesn´t satisfy me question. Can you have a look and tell me if i have to improve my question? All the best and thank you in advance :)

Comment: @Weiss it seems like r2evans's answer is better than one I could make myself tbqh! I don't often use base plot() because it is quite limited. Is there a reason you're not using ggplot?

Comment: @Mark sorry for taking so long to answer u. I had a very stressfull week... no there aren´t any reasons why I don´t use ggplot... Should I rewirte this?

Comment: that's okay! I hope it's getting better now, the stressful situation I mean

Comment: I'll have a go at writing something with ggplot on your question in the next few days